# Определить, есть ли простой путь в графе, проходящий через все его вершины

Tags: алгоритм, матрицы, поиск, графы, поиск-пути

Граф задан матрицей смежности. Необходимо определить, есть ли в нем хотя бы один простой путь, проходящий через все его вершины и если есть, вывести его на экран.

Каким алгоритмом лучше воспользоваться?

Comment: [Задача о гамильтоновом пути](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала считаете количество нечётных вершин. Если их больше двух - смело пишете, что пути нет.

Далее - обычный обход в глубину, ищется путь, длина которого на 1 меньше количества вершин, повторный проход не разрешён.

Если нечётных вершин две - ищем из одной в другую.

Если одна - из неё.

Если нет - из всех.

---

**UPDATE**

Пардон, ошибся. Написал для варианта прохода по всем рёбрам. Для прохода по всем узлам - просто поиск в глубину из всех узлов.

Comment: [0 1 0 0 1]
[1 0 1 1 0]
[0 1 0 0 1]
[0 1 0 0 1]
[1 0 1 1 0]
(Это строки матрицы смежности графа по порядку)
А как в таком случае найти простой путь в данном графе? Нечетных вершин две (2 и 5), однако из одной в другую простого пути через все вершины нет, но есть, например, путь из 1 в 3 (1->2->4->5->3).

Comment: @Atemyn Пардон, ошибся. Написал для варианта прохода по всем рёбрам. Для прохода по всем узлам - просто поиск в глубину из всех узлов.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за помощь. Пойду писать